# Drupal Ubercart Merchant ID and Key are incorrect?

Tags: ubercart

When I checkout in Ubercart the merchant key and merchant id are incorrect. In my configuration they are correct, but when the login credentials are displayed during checkout, they are jumbled.

I am using the uc_domain module to manage different payment gateways per domain. My original domain is working correctly, but my new domain, as seen in the image, is not working correctly.

The main error that I am getting is this:

> DOMDocument::loadXML() [function.DOMDocument-loadXML]: error parsing
>   attribute name in Entity, line: 1 in
>   .../ubercart/payment/uc_cybersource/uc_cybersource.soap.inc on line
>   31.

Screenshot:
 http://yfrog.com/gzv1tpp

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I made sure that the proper soap packages were installed. 
Then I went on to create new credit card encryption keys for each domain. Right now I am waiting on SSL certs so that Drupal can generate new credit card encryption keys for each domain. I hope it works!